# How do I know what type I can cast to on a GetRow()?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, xtragrid

```
void gridControl1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    GridControl grid = sender as GridControl; 
    DXMouseEventArgs args = e as DXMouseEventArgs;
    BaseHitInfo hitInfo = grid.Views[0].CalcHitInfo(args.Location);
    GridHitInfo gridHit = hitInfo as GridHitInfo;
    if (GridHitTest.RowCell == gridHit.HitTest) {
        int rowHandle = gridHit.RowHandle;
        grid.MainView.GetRow(rowHandle);//GetRow returns Object. I need to cast this to a Type to make it useful
    }
}
```

I have the [documentation](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_GetRowtopic) for GetRow(). I have been unable to extract much more useful info than I can already pull via intellisense.

How do I know what I can cast this to?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The documentation seems reasonably clear to me:

> This method's return value depends upon the type of the View's data source. If the data source is a System.Data.DataTable or a System.Data.DataView, this method returns a System.Data.DataRowView object. If the data source is a custom list of items, the appropriate list item is returned.

So what *is* your source? Is it a `DataTable` / `DataView`? If so, cast to `DataRowView`. If it's a `List<T>` or something similar, then cast to the element type. I assume you *do* know at compile-time what your data source type is?

Comment: Ok.  Thanks.  It is being populated by a List<SomeModel>.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey: So then you cast to `SomeModel`, by the looks of it.

Comment: @John Skeet - Indeed. I missed the remark in the documenation.  I'm working on a new project at a new company and rushing against a tight deadline.  So I'm making dumb mistakes.  Thanks for your help.